# Registering one application multiple times (aliases) in netflix eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I would like to register one spring cloud application running instance to eureka with 3 different names, as we would like to serve different APIs from the same module.
As I could not find anything around this topic, I'm a bit worried if this is a bad concept. But if it is okay, I would like to have some guidance on how to do it with spring cloud in a idiomatic way.

Comment: It's not possible at the current time.

Comment: @spencergibb any chances to see this in a near future?

Comment: Not likely. You'd have to file an issue upstream in eureka.